# Build Status on iTune Connect Invalid Binary?

Tags: ios, coronasdk, app-store-connect

I have to build from Application loader ipa file for store then first status is uploaded then after few minutes Invalid Binary.

```
CFBundleIconFile = "Icon.png",
                        CFBundleIconFiles = {
                                "Icon-60@3x.png",
                                "Icon-Small-40@3x.png",
                                "Icon-Small@3x.png",
                                "Icon.png",
                                "Icon@2x.png",
                                "Icon-Small-40.png",
                                "Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
                                "Icon-60.png",
                                "Icon-60@2x.png",
                                "Icon-72.png",
                                "Icon-72@2x.png",
                                "Icon-76.png",
                                "Icon-76@2x.png",
                                "Icon-Small-50.png",
                                "Icon-Small-50@2x.png",
                                "Icon-Small.png",
                                "Icon-Small@2x.png",
                                },

                            UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false,
                            UIPrerenderedIcon = true,
                            UIStatusBarHidden = true,
                            CFBundleVersion = "1.4",
                            UIAppFonts = { "TIMESBD.TTF","TIMESBD.TTF" },
                            MinimumOSVersion = "6.0",
```

I have to work on corona platform.

Please anybody help me ????

Comment: r u uploaded the first version or upgraded versions

Comment: Apple should have sent an email message to you with explanations why the binary is invalid. Maybe the binary doesn't include 64-bit support.

Comment: First version Upload on it.